# MFC: Disable Scripts in CHtmlView?

Tags: mfc

I found that links can be disabled simply by `EnableWindow(FALSE)` for the `CHtmlView` control. Looks good, can't click the link.

Now, is there a way to disable scripts when using `CHtmlView`?

I didn't see anything that stood out in the docs.

TIA!!

Comment: You can remove `<script>...</script>` out of html content and load a new page. However, you may still have other scripts within the page. Another option (not recommended) you can use the registry to globally disable the script for IE.

Comment: The html code could be encoded right, so it could get complicated trying to just find <script> ?

Comment: `<` and `>` are a special html characters, you can do case insensitive find/replace on `<script` and `</script>` to find the beginning and the end. However there could be more scrips, or `onmousehover` etc. javascripts within the elements which are nearly impossible to deal with.